# Find and replace url inside <style>

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, find

I've this css:

```
    <style> .thumbs{background:url('/img/thumbs.jpg') no-repeat;}</style>
```

Now i want to find and replace the url: `/img/thumbs.jpg` to `http://abc.xyz/img/no-thumb.jpg`

Is it possible?

Comment: Why not just update the source file?

Comment: because i've used `background:url('%urlthumb%')` and i want to replace that with my own picture which is not possible manually.

Comment: Please explain your intentions. What are you trying to achieve? You can parse style element with javascript, but i'm not sure if this is really necessary.

Comment: I'm working on a html site which has %urlthumb% tag. It generates a default thumbnail for blog. And i don't like that pic so i want to replace that with my own pic.

Answer (score 1):

> try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var background = $('.thumbs').css('background');
    var a = background.split('"');
    var new_image = '';

     $.each(a,function(index, element){
        var str = element.split('/').slice(3,5).join('/');
        if(str == 'img/thumbs.jpg'){
          new_image = 'http://abc.xyz/img/no-thumb.jpg';
        }
    })

    if(new_image !=''){
        $('.thumbs').css('background',"url('"+new_image+"') no-repeat");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 window.onload = function(){
       document.getElementByClassName('thumbs').style.background = "url('http://abc.xyz/img/no-thumb.jpg')";
   }
```

Comment: Thanks but, i want to replace only when the css has `/img/thumbs.jpg` this url! Thats why i mentioned find and replace.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `thumbs` css class with additional instance:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // once head is loaded add style element with class definition that will override .thumbs
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; // get head dom element
    head.innerHTML += '<style> .thumbs{background:url("https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/leaves.png") no-repeat;}</style>'; // put additional style at the end of head (this will overide thumbs), you can put any url background here. 
</script>
```

Working example below (https://jsbin.com/mehuhokopi/edit?html,output):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style> .thumbs{background:url('/img/thumbs.jpg') no-repeat;}</style>
    <style>
      .test {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: red;
      }      
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // once head is loaded add style element with class definition that will override .thumbs
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; // get head dom element
        head.innerHTML += '<style> .thumbs{background:url("https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/leaves.png") no-repeat;}</style>'; // put additional style at the end of head (this will overide thumbs), you can put any url background here. 
    </script>        
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="test thumbs">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```